# in linux debian, how to cut the default gateway from route

Tags: linux, bash, debian

I am trying to cut the default gateway from route

```
route | grep UG |cut -f 2 -d ' '
```

but I am getting an emty line...

the nurmal output of route is

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         10.0.2.2        0.0.0.0         UG    1024   0        0 eth0
10.0.2.0        *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0
```

please help me...
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
route -n | grep '^0.0.0'  | awk '{print $2}'
```